# Fragments with own actionbar items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I've been searching for a few hours, and I can't get this work :

I have 2 fragments, I add a different menu item in each of them in the action bar.
[image]

It's working as you can see but what I want is that an item stays in his fragment "frame" (but still in the action bar) The items should be separated and stay on top of their own fragment like in the picture below.

[image]

I've read I need to call setHasOptionsMenu in the method onCreate() of each fragment, but it still doesn't work as I'd like.

Here is my code :

MainActivity (hosting my 2 fragments)

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Frag1 f1 = new Frag1();
    Frag2 f2 = new Frag2();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frag1, f1);
    ft.replace(R.id.frag2, f2);
    ft.commit();

   }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/frag1"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      >
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/frag2"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      >
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Frag1.java

```
public class Frag1 extends SherlockFragment{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_content, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.add(0, 12, 1, "Frag 1").setTitle("MENU ITEM 1").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);


   }

}
```

Frag2.java

```
public class Frag2 extends SherlockFragment{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_content2, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.add(5, 15, 101, "Frag 2").setTitle("MENU ITEM 2").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);


   }

}
```

The Layouts of the fragments are simple LinearLayout containing a TextView

Could someone please point me to the right solution ?

Answer (score 1):

> The items should be separated and stay on top of their own fragment like in the picture below.

That is not supported and goes against [the Android design guidelines for the action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). Also, watch the [Android Design in Action video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I) where Google engineers specifically point out these sorts of action bar problems (at around the 14:10 mark).